# Google AdMob Unity: Only test ads work (in Unity Editor) but no real ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

My admob account is linked to the app in play store, status "ready", AdMob app ID also added into ad settings in Unity, added in the real ad unit ID, test ad showing in Unity, waited a week...

Result: no real ads

My event is calling RequestAndLoadInterstitialAd() and ShowInterstitialAd(), which works in Unity with the test ad. I expected it to work once the test ad implemented successfully.

```
    using UnityEngine.Events;
    using UnityEngine;
    using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
    using GoogleMobileAds.Common;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class GoogleAdMobController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private AppOpenAd appOpenAd;
        private BannerView bannerView;
        private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
        private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
        private RewardedInterstitialAd rewardedInterstitialAd;
        private float deltaTime;
        private bool isShowingAppOpenAd;
        public UnityEvent OnAdLoadedEvent;
        public UnityEvent OnAdFailedToLoadEvent;
        public UnityEvent OnAdOpeningEvent;
        public UnityEvent OnAdFailedToShowEvent;
        public UnityEvent OnUserEarnedRewardEvent;
        public UnityEvent OnAdClosedEvent;
        public bool showFpsMeter = true;
        public Text fpsMeter;
        public Text statusText;


        #region UNITY MONOBEHAVIOR METHODS

        public void Start()
        {
            MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);

            List<String> deviceIds = new List<String>() { AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator };

            // Add some test device IDs (replace with your own device IDs).
    #if UNITY_IPHONE
            deviceIds.Add("b77a5c561934e089)--a185c62eba2497c95197140e5282b27a");
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            deviceIds.Add("b77a5c561934e089)--a185c62eba2497c95197140e5282b27a");
    #endif

            // Configure TagForChildDirectedTreatment and test device IDs.
            RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration =
                new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
                .SetTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TagForChildDirectedTreatment.Unspecified)
                .SetTestDeviceIds(deviceIds).build();
            MobileAds.SetRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);

            // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
            MobileAds.Initialize(HandleInitCompleteAction);
        }

        private void HandleInitCompleteAction(InitializationStatus initstatus)
        {
            // Callbacks from GoogleMobileAds are not guaranteed to be called on
            // main thread.
            // In this example we use MobileAdsEventExecutor to schedule these calls on
            // the next Update() loop.
            MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() =>
            {
                statusText.text = "Initialization complete";
            //  RequestBannerAd();
            });
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (showFpsMeter)
            {
                fpsMeter.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.1f;
                float fps = 1.0f / deltaTime;
                fpsMeter.text = string.Format("{0:0.} fps", fps);
            }
            else
            {
                fpsMeter.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region HELPER METHODS

        private AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
        {
            return new AdRequest.Builder()
                .AddKeyword("unity-admob-sample")
                .Build();
        }

        public void OnApplicationPause(bool paused)
        {
            // Display the app open ad when the app is foregrounded.
            if (!paused)
            {
                ShowAppOpenAd();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region BANNER ADS

        public void RequestBannerAd()
        {
            statusText.text = "Requesting Banner Ad.";

            // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
    #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

            // Clean up banner before reusing
            if (bannerView != null)
            {
                bannerView.Destroy();
            }

            // Create a 320x50 banner at top of the screen
            bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);

            // Add Event Handlers
            bannerView.OnAdLoaded += (sender, args) => OnAdLoadedEvent.Invoke();
            bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += (sender, args) => OnAdFailedToLoadEvent.Invoke();
            bannerView.OnAdOpening += (sender, args) => OnAdOpeningEvent.Invoke();
            bannerView.OnAdClosed += (sender, args) => OnAdClosedEvent.Invoke();

            // Load a banner ad
            bannerView.LoadAd(CreateAdRequest());
        }

        public void DestroyBannerAd()
        {
            if (bannerView != null)
            {
                bannerView.Destroy();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region INTERSTITIAL ADS

        public void RequestAndLoadInterstitialAd()
        {
            // statusText.text = "Requesting Interstitial Ad.";

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2334240444886107/9358512518";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
    #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

            // Clean up interstitial before using it
            if (interstitialAd != null)
            {
                interstitialAd.Destroy();
            }
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

            // Add Event Handlers
            interstitialAd.OnAdLoaded += (sender, args) => OnAdLoadedEvent.Invoke();
            interstitialAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += (sender, args) => OnAdFailedToLoadEvent.Invoke();
            interstitialAd.OnAdOpening += (sender, args) => OnAdOpeningEvent.Invoke();
            interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += (sender, args) => OnAdClosedEvent.Invoke();

            // Load an interstitial ad
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(CreateAdRequest());
        }

        public void ShowInterstitialAd()
        {
            if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
            {
                interstitialAd.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                statusText.text = "Interstitial ad is not ready yet";
            }
        }

        public void DestroyInterstitialAd()
        {
            if (interstitialAd != null)
            {
                interstitialAd.Destroy();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region REWARDED ADS

        public void RequestAndLoadRewardedAd()
        {
            statusText.text = "Requesting Rewarded Ad.";
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
    #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

            // create new rewarded ad instance
            rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adUnitId);

            // Add Event Handlers
            rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += (sender, args) => OnAdLoadedEvent.Invoke();
            rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += (sender, args) => OnAdFailedToLoadEvent.Invoke();
            rewardedAd.OnAdOpening += (sender, args) => OnAdOpeningEvent.Invoke();
            rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += (sender, args) => OnAdFailedToShowEvent.Invoke();
            rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += (sender, args) => OnAdClosedEvent.Invoke();
            rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += (sender, args) => OnUserEarnedRewardEvent.Invoke();

            // Create empty ad request
            rewardedAd.LoadAd(CreateAdRequest());
        }

        public void ShowRewardedAd()
        {
            if (rewardedAd != null)
            {
                rewardedAd.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                statusText.text = "Rewarded ad is not ready yet.";
            }
        }

        public void RequestAndLoadRewardedInterstitialAd()
        {
            statusText.text = "Requesting Rewarded Interstitial Ad.";

            // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
                string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
                string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866";
    #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

            // Create an interstitial.
            RewardedInterstitialAd.LoadAd(adUnitId, CreateAdRequest(), (rewardedInterstitialAd, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "RewardedInterstitialAd load failed, error: " + error;
                    });
                    return;
                }
                this.rewardedInterstitialAd = rewardedInterstitialAd;
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    statusText.text = "RewardedInterstitialAd loaded";
                });
                // Register for ad events.
                this.rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdDidPresentFullScreenContent += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "Rewarded Interstitial presented.";
                    });
                };
                this.rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdDidDismissFullScreenContent += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "Rewarded Interstitial dismissed.";
                    });
                    this.rewardedInterstitialAd = null;
                };
                this.rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdFailedToPresentFullScreenContent += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "Rewarded Interstitial failed to present.";
                    });
                    this.rewardedInterstitialAd = null;
                };
            });
        }

        public void ShowRewardedInterstitialAd()
        {
            if (rewardedInterstitialAd != null)
            {
                rewardedInterstitialAd.Show((reward) => {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "User Rewarded: " + reward.Amount;
                    });
                });
            }
            else
            {
                statusText.text = "Rewarded ad is not ready yet.";
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region APPOPEN ADS

        public void RequestAndLoadAppOpenAd()
        {
            statusText.text = "Requesting App Open Ad.";
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5662855259";
    #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif
            // create new app open ad instance
            AppOpenAd.LoadAd(adUnitId, ScreenOrientation.Portrait, CreateAdRequest(), (appOpenAd, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "AppOpenAd load failed, error: " + error;
                    });
                    return;
                }
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    statusText.text = "AppOpenAd loaded. Please background the app and return.";
                });
                this.appOpenAd = appOpenAd;
            });
        }

        public void ShowAppOpenAd()
        {
            if (isShowingAppOpenAd)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (appOpenAd == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            // Register for ad events.
            this.appOpenAd.OnAdDidDismissFullScreenContent += (sender, args) =>
            {
                isShowingAppOpenAd = false;
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    Debug.Log("AppOpenAd dismissed.");
                    if (this.appOpenAd != null)
                    {
                        this.appOpenAd.Destroy();
                        this.appOpenAd = null;
                    }
                });
            };
            this.appOpenAd.OnAdFailedToPresentFullScreenContent += (sender, args) =>
            {
                isShowingAppOpenAd = false;
                var msg = args.AdError.GetMessage();
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    statusText.text = "AppOpenAd present failed, error: " + msg;
                    if (this.appOpenAd != null)
                    {
                        this.appOpenAd.Destroy();
                        this.appOpenAd = null;
                    }
                });
            };
            this.appOpenAd.OnAdDidPresentFullScreenContent += (sender, args) =>
            {
                isShowingAppOpenAd = true;
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    Debug.Log("AppOpenAd presented.");
                });
            };
            this.appOpenAd.OnAdDidRecordImpression += (sender, args) =>
            {
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    Debug.Log("AppOpenAd recorded an impression.");
                });
            };
            this.appOpenAd.OnPaidEvent += (sender, args) =>
            {
                string currencyCode = args.AdValue.CurrencyCode;
                long adValue = args.AdValue.Value;
                string suffix = "AppOpenAd received a paid event.";
                MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                    string msg = string.Format("{0} (currency: {1}, value: {2}", suffix, currencyCode, adValue);
                    statusText.text = msg;
                });
            };
            appOpenAd.Show();
        }

        #endregion


        #region AD INSPECTOR

        public void OpenAdInspector()
        {
            statusText.text = "Open Ad Inspector.";

            MobileAds.OpenAdInspector((error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    string errorMessage = error.GetMessage();
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "Ad Inspector failed to open, error: " + errorMessage;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
                        statusText.text = "Ad Inspector closed.";
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two things wrong. One, I was using my live adUnit ID not the test one. The second issue was I was calling the load and show methods at the same time which worked in Unity, but on Android it seems there needs to be more time for the ad to load.

What I did to get the test ads on mobile device:

1. Set up the test device like HTugsadK said https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433
2. Change the adUnitId in RequestAndLoadInterstitialAd() to the interstitial test ID from here https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/test-ads#add_your_test_device_programmatically
   For production this should be changed back to the real adUnitId.
3. Change the end of the RequestAndLoadInterstitialAd() method and Invoke the show method with a 5 second delay. Now in your event you only have to call this method.

   ```
    public void RequestAndLoadInterstitialAd()
        {
            // statusText.text = "Requesting Interstitial Ad.";

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
    #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

            // Clean up interstitial before using it
            if (interstitialAd != null)
            {
                interstitialAd.Destroy();
            }
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

            // Add Event Handlers
            interstitialAd.OnAdLoaded += (sender, args) => OnAdLoadedEvent.Invoke();
            interstitialAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += (sender, args) => OnAdFailedToLoadEvent.Invoke();
            interstitialAd.OnAdOpening += (sender, args) => OnAdOpeningEvent.Invoke();
            interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += (sender, args) => OnAdClosedEvent.Invoke();

            // Load an interstitial ad
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(CreateAdRequest());
            Invoke("ShowInterstitialAd", 5);
        }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If your test device (You can add this from Admob) shows your ADs as expected you should be fine. After some requests, your game will start to show real ads. Admob does not give real ads immediately, it needs some request to show real ads. But as I say you have to be sure your test devices show ads correctly.

- And I also recommend check compatible admob SDK and Unity versions. Because they have bugs sometimes. You can check it in Admob GitHub page.
  You can check here:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases

Comment: Does Unity running the test ad count as correct configuration? I am having a lot of trouble setting up a test device (phone not pairing in android studio)

Comment: Yes it counts, but I recommend adding a test device from Admob, in Admod settings, there is a test device adding a tab, you can add your Android device as a test device without Android Studio. You can check: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433

Comment: Thank you I did that now, the message at the bottom of my phone screen says "initialization complete" but I still don't see a test ad in the phone

Comment: If you don't see any test ad (especially interstitial or rewarded) in your phone (or any physical test device), that means there is a problem with your Ad's call, I recommend checking log messages from your device with Unity and Visual Studio debug tool. Just check your adfailed or loaded event triggers (OnLoaded, OnFailed ...). For more info: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1320966/android-debug-usb.html

Comment: There are no such messages in the debugger from Unity, like I said the test ad comes up in Unity. My phone is also not paired up to Visual Studio, it can't find it at all and USB debugging is enabled. This is ridiculous, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here Is The Solution

```
public void Start()
{
    // When true all events raised by GoogleMobileAds will be raised
    // on the Unity main thread. The default value is false.
    MobileAds.RaiseAdEventsOnUnityMainThread = true;
    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.Initialize((initStatus) =>
    {
        Dictionary<string, AdapterStatus> map = initStatus.getAdapterStatusMap();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AdapterStatus> keyValuePair in map)
        {
            string className = keyValuePair.Key;
            AdapterStatus status = keyValuePair.Value;
            switch (status.InitializationState)
            {
                case AdapterState.NotReady:
                    // The adapter initialization did not complete.
                    MonoBehaviour.print("Adapter: " + className + " not ready.");
                    break;
                case AdapterState.Ready:
                    // The adapter was successfully initialized.
                    MonoBehaviour.print("Adapter: " + className + " is initialized.");
                    break;
            }
        }

        // This callback is called once the MobileAds SDK is initialized.
        LoadRewardedAd();

    });
}
```

This Works For Me, Real ads Are Appearing now in mobile version

Comment: I copied this from here https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediate